# Create a variable with string, array or multiple values

Tags: theme-development, templates, wp-admin, page-template, variables

I'm running some functions that will allow a user to register their own custom templates to my custom theme from an external directory. They can see these page templates in the `wp-admin` and they render on the frontend.

Everything works fine with this, but I would like to register files from multiple directories, not just one directory.

I need to make `$file` equal multiple directories. I've tried an array. I've tried `&&` and a couple other things, including the below code, but nothing works.

I'm not a pro, but what am I missing here? Can this be done? In the code below I see that the last `$file =` takes priority over the previous `$file =`.

So is there a way I can make `$file` equals multiple paths?

In short, I want `$file` to consider multiple paths.

The code probably explains itself what I am trying to achieve.

```
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/home/'            . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/pages/'           . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/blog/'            . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/single-posts/'    . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/products/'        . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/templates/'       . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    $file = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH .      '/products/'        . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );


if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the last `$file` takes priority over the previous

That's because you assign the new value to the `$file` variable at every line.

The only way I see you can do it by using the array:

```
<?php
// define directory list
$directories = array(
    'home',
    'pages',
    'blog',
    'single-posts',
    'products',
    'templates',
    'products'
);
// run through directories and return the result for each of them
foreach($directories as $directory) {
    // create path for each directory
    $path = CUSTOM_OPTION_BACKEND_TEMPLATES_PATH . '/' . $directory . '/' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    // return path if file exists
    if ( file_exists( $path ) )
        return $path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I'm not very familiar with the php options, just some, so the **foreach** is new to me to actually use. But now I get what it is doing in this case so I can have it in mind for the future. Appreciate it @MaxYudin